# R. How to create a new column, returning i based on another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, NA, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1', NA,'2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
```

I want a new column employ.data$NA that returns i in `employ.data$employee` if `[i]` in any other row is NA.

I have tried this for 1 column but getting errors

```
employ.data$NA = NA 
{for (i in 1:nrow(Eurostat)) 
  {
  if (startdate[i] = "NA")  employ.data$employee[i]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, in the `if` statement, it should be `==`, not `=`

Comment: Also `NA` is a really bad name for a column variable as `NA` is a logical constant in R denoting a missing value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `complete.cases()` from base R -

```
employ.data$missingFlag <- !complete.cases(employ.data)

    employee salary  startdate missingFlag
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01       FALSE
2 Peter Gynn     NA       <NA>        TRUE
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14       FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to vectorize it and use an `ifelse` statement:

```
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate, stringsAsFactors = F)
employ.data["missing"] = with(employ.data, ifelse(is.na(startdate), employee, NA))
employ.data
    employee salary  startdate    missing
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01       <NA>
2 Peter Gynn     NA       <NA> Peter Gynn
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14       <NA>
```

Alternatively, to check all columns, use `any`:

```
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate, stringsAsFactors = F)
employ.data["something_missing"] = apply(employ.data, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
employ.data
    employee salary  startdate something_missing
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01             FALSE
2 Peter Gynn     NA       <NA>              TRUE
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14             FALSE
```

The construct above will give you booleans. If you want to get a column of the names, you can combine it with `ifelse`.

On a more general note, instantiating a column first and then looping through the dataframe to populate it is not particularly `Rtistic`, and I would suggest to avoid this strategy whenever possible. The `apply`-family of functions are very powerful, and `ifelse` is too. `dplyr`'s `mutate` combined with `case_when` statments can also be used in case you want something more SQL-like.

Just for pedagocial reasons, here is your code in working version. Please don't use it, just try to understand the differences.

```
employ.data$missing = NA 
for (i in 1:nrow(employ.data)) {
  if (is.na(employ.data$startdate[i])){ 
         employ.data$missing[i] <- employ.data$employee[i]
        }
}
```

Importantly, note that `"NA"` is interpreted as a string. To test if a value is `NA`, you need to use e.g. `is.na`. After all, testing if `42 == NA` is ambiguous. The value is missing. It may or may not be equal to 42, so the test will return `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done quite easily with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, NA, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1', NA,'2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

employ.data <- employ.data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(missing = any(is.na(c(salary, startdate))))
```